# Class-path in manifest not read when running jar in Unix

Tags: unix, jar, manifest, noclassdeffounderror

I have a client application that needs to run on Unix.  It works fine in Windows but i get a NoClassDefFound exception in unix. Here's my manifest file:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 2.3 (IBM Corporation)
Main-Class: com.main.Client
Class-Path: lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar lib/comm
 ons-logging-api-1.1.jar lib/log4j-1.2.12.jar

And the Client.jar structure:

com
com/main
lib
meta-inf

To run it, i use the command below:

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/java -jar Client.jar
```

It works fine in windows.  Somehow i think that its not reading the manifest right.  Help please! Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding a lib folder with the required jars locally and it works fine. So i guess the class-path is read correctly but somehow the jar file is not extracted properly?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make sure you have defined your CLASSPATH variable for the user that is running the program.

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
```

if there is nothing shown from the above, then export it

```
$ export CLASSPATH="/lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar:/your/other/paths"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

But should'nt the Class-Path attribute in the manifest file handle that for me? What i want to have is a client application that is independent so that it can be ported to other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your meta-inf folder is in lower-case?